# When is a spacetime a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity

While reading $\textrm{Present status of the Penrose Inequality}$ by Marc Mars, 2009, I was confused with the following statement:

> ... in order to determine whether a space-time is a black hole, detailed knowledge of its global future behaviour is required.

Why is that ?

Comment: That's awfully little context. Can you cite a bit more than that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common definition of a black home is the portion of the spacetime manifold $\mathcal{M}$ that is $\mathcal{M} - J^-(ℐ^+)$, the manifold minus the causal past of null future infinity. That is, it's the region of spacetime where no signal can escape to infinity at some point in the future. This requires you to know the global structure of spacetime (such as the existence of null infinity and such).

Comment: If no physical signal can escape, how can you know such a region? You can't.

Comment: @CuriousOne You're going to have to elaborate.

Comment: @0celo7: The interior of a black holes, more generally all physics behind  event horizons poses a serious problem for the scientific method. One can't describe what one can't measure. Unless there is a quantum peephole that get us behind the veil, the only technically correct scientific statement is: we don't know.